# Codeigniter sorting data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a ptoblem with sorting `$_post` data in codeigniter.

Controller:

```
public function filter(){
 ...
  $this->model->method($this->request->post);
 ...
}
```

Model:
`$keys` = `$_POST`-data

```
public function($keys) {
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('table1 t1');
   $this->db->join('table2 t2', 't2.id = t1.id', 'left');

   if(!empty($keys['value1']){
     $this->db->where('t1.column', $keys['value1']);
   }
   if(!empty($keys['value2']){
     $this->db->where('t1.column', $keys['value2']);
   }

   if($keys['value3'] || $keys['value4'] || $keys['value5']){
       $array = array($keys['value3'], $keys['value4'], $keys['value5']);
       $this->db->where_in('t2.column', $array);
   }

   $query = $this->db->get()->result();
   return $query;
}
```

table1

```
id value1 valu2
 1 23      24
 2 12      15
```

table2

```
t1_id value (this contain value of value3, value4, value5)
 2     7
 2     19
 2     13
 2     3
 1     7
 1     13
 1     3
```

It works, but if set a `value3..value5`, then selects all values, not a priority `table1` value, I need to to do value1 and value2 it has been a priority before `value3..value5`
Sry for my bad english, tnx!

For example:
products_table

```
product_id value1 value2
  1           13   9
  2           13   9
  3           14  10
```

product_to_atributes

```
product_id atribute_id
  1         2
  1         3
  1         4
  2         3
  2         4
```

product_atributes

```
atribute_id  atribute_name
    2            atr_name
    3            atr_name2
    4            atr_name3
```

I need select list of product, where `value1 = '13'` and `value2 = '9'` `and product_to_atributes.atribute_id IN(2,4)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$this->db->or_where_in();
```

your code should be:

```
if($keys['value3'] || $keys['value4'] || $keys['value5']){
       $array = array($keys['value3'], $keys['value4'], $keys['value5']);
       $this->db->or_where_in('t2.column', $array);
   }
```

Comment: not working, `$this->db->or_where_in()`, I get a all record list

Comment: you can decide use or_where Or and_where

Comment: if use `->where('t2.column', $keys['value3']);` and `->where('t2.column', $keys['value4']);` and `->where('t2.column', $keys['value5']);`
not working - results is empty

`t2.column` it's a one field in table.
if value is one - working `$keys['value3']`
if value is multi - not

Comment: see the example in top